# How can I change the install directory for Photoshop CS4?

Tags: windows-7, installation, photoshop-cs4

I just got a new computer with a SSD for booting (C:) and a bigger HDD for programs and other files (D:). Now I want to install Photoshop CS4 and I want it to install on D. but the installer would not let me chose the destination.
[image]

As you can see, there is enough space on the SSD but that shall be used for other programs.
Is there some way to change the directory where the program files go to without filling the C drive first or hacking some pathes in the registry?

Comment: I hear, you need a junction point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan D has stated, you need to create a Junction Point. If you are not sure how to do this manually, then [LinkMagic](http://www.rekenwonder.com/linkmagic.htm) provides an easy solution.

From CS5 onwards you are able to change the default installation directory.